# GeForce GTX * in Matlab?

Tags: graphics-cards

This benchmark [here](http://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-750-Ti-vs-Nvidia-GTX-670/2187vs2181) shows that GTX 670 is better in some conditions. 
GTX 670 supports Cuda 3, while GTX 750 Ti supports CUDA 5 but GTX 960 supports Cuda 5.2. 
However, I have no experience how much this difference could be in reliability, accuracy and computation speed.
I would like to understand differences between Cuda 5 and 5.2 in Matlab computation, and this way, understand which GTX to choose.

How can you decide which GPU is better for scientific computation in Matlab?

Comment: Which version do *you* need? That's more important than what we recommend. If you need 5.2, then there isn't a question here

Comment: @Andy I need a version that is well supported by Matlab. I would like to also understand the differences between 5.2 and 5 Cuda.

Comment: The second part of that question is off topic here.

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/products/matlab/choosing_hardware.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop#_Graphics_Processing_Unit_1